# How to stream data from grpc server to any pub/sub application

Tags: grpc, publish-subscribe

I want to stream gRPC stream data to any pubsub (nats io pub sub) but I am confused on how to achieve it, as client needs to send at least on request to server to start the streaming. How can I achieve that

[image: Diagram]

Now one thing I can think of is publish the data from gRPC client to the pub sub server

```
gRPC Ssrver ---> gRPC Client ---> publish to the pubsub
```

But would it be a good approach?.

I know its an open ended question but any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: You could implement all of this using gRPC/gRPC-Web or have an application (Pubsub App?) that streams data from the gRPC server and pushes it out using NATS (or whatever pub/sub protocol you choose). You need to consider whether each `subscriber` needs an individual stream from the gRPC server or not (i.e. is the stream generic or customised for each end consumer). Without more information I don't think its really possible to answer (and with more info this is likely to become opinion based and, thus, off topic).

Comment: I dont want to involve grpc web ,as it still uses http 1.1  and I dnt want to involve proxy tool like envoy for that ,the data stream would be same for all clients @Brits

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; gRPC-Web will run fine over HTTP/2 (source [this](https://grpc.io/blog/state-of-grpc-web/) and I run it over HTTP/2 myself). Whatever approach you end up with will have some form of "proxy tool" (whether it's proxying gRPC-Web to gRPC, NATS to gRPC or something else to gRPC); if your backend runs gRPC you need something to proxy requests to gRPC. Note that if you use NATS then it's probably going to be NATS over websockets (the restrictions imposed by the browser really limit your options).